# angular2 transformRequest usage for xml to json conversion

Tags: json, xml, angular

I managed to convert xml response into json format in angular 1 using the code below. But how can I use similar code in angular2,

```
var xml = function () {
        $http.get("./app/sampleXML.xml", 
                { 
                    transformResponse: function (cnv) { 
                        var x2js = new X2JS(); 
                        var aftCnv = x2js.xml_str2json(cnv); 
                        return aftCnv; 
                    } 
                }) 
        .success(function (response) { 
            console.log(response);
        }); 
    }
```

Angular2:

```
getXml() {
   this.http.get('../../jsonConfig/sampleXML.xml')
    .map(response => response.text())
    .subscribe(data => {
        if(data) {
           console.log(data);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me :

```
xml_str2json(extractXML(data.text(),'string1','string2'))
```

where `xml2json` comes from the following library :

https://github.com/abdmob/x2js

and `extractXML` is a string function that enables me to extract the xml body from  the SOAP response.

I could not find any document on the methods that could be applied on a Response.

Hope this may help.

Cheers.